# How to use Kendo data-bind attribute in Html.CheckBoxFor() helper

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to bind checkbox checked value from kendo observable. All the examples online show data-bind attribute in declarative syntax like:

```html
<div class="demo-section k-content wide">
<input type="checkbox" value="Apple" data-bind="checked: isSelected" />
</div>
```

```js
<script>
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        isSelected: false,
    });
kendo.bind($("div.demo-section"), viewModel);
</script>
```

How do i bind (or add data-bind to)

```cs
@Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(m => m.data).HtmlAttributes(new {@class="chkbox"})
```

checked value with kendo observable?

I tried:

```cs
$(".chkbox").kendoCheckBox({ //does kendoCheckBox even exist?
   checked: viewModel.isSelected
})
```

and kendo.CheckBoxFor takes only one arguments so I can't do:

```cs
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.data, new { data_bind = "checked:isSelected" });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the "data_bind: whatever" to the HtmlAttributes anonymous object of Kendo.CheckBoxFor(), i.e.

```
@Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(m => m.data).HtmlAttributes(new {@class="chkbox", data_bind = "checked: isSelected"})
```

I have done this many times:

```
<div id="checkBoxDiv">
    @Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(m => m.BooleanField).HtmlAttributes(new { data_bind = "checked: isBooleanFieldSelected" })
    @Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(m => m.OtherBooleanField).HtmlAttributes(new { data_bind = "checked: isOtherBooleanFieldSelected" })
</div>

<script>
    var model = kendo.observable({
        isBooleanFieldSelected: true,
        isOtherBooleanFieldSelected: false
    });
    kendo.bind($("#checkBoxDiv"), model);
</script>
```

Comment: Rock on! Thank you